# How to fix exception System.TypeLoadException: VTable setup of type Xfx.Controls.Droid.Renderers.XfxCardViewRendererDroid failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cardview

I'm trying to implement XfxCardView in my Xamarin Forms app. The exception occurs when the app is loading. There is no error while building. I don't know why I'm getting this exception. The exception is

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeLoadException: VTable setup of type Xfx.Controls.Droid.Renderers.XfxCardViewRendererDroid failed
```

This is my XAML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xfx="clr-namespace:Xfx;assembly=Xfx.Controls"

             x:Class="ScrollerSample.Gallery" BackgroundColor="White">
    <StackLayout Margin="20,0,0,0">
        <Label  Text="Top specialitiest" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Bold,10"  FontSize="20" />


    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
      <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <StackLayout   x:Name="StackGallery" Padding="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="RESTAURANTS NEAR YOU" TextColor="#595959" HeightRequest="30"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="25 Restaurants finded" TextColor="#d9d9d9" HeightRequest="20"></Label>

        </Grid>
        <StackLayout>

            <xfx:XfxCardView CornerRadius="3" Elevation="3">
                <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0">
                    <Image Source="http://lorempixel.com/1024/200/abstract" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Aspect="Fill" />
                    <Label Text="hi judson" TextColor="Black" Margin="8"/>



                </StackLayout>
            </xfx:XfxCardView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is the code in MainActivity

```
using Xfx;

namespace ScrollerSample.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "ScrollerSample", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            XfxControls.Init();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

I have added all the necessary codes required for displaying the card view but I'm still getting the exception. I'm using [this Link](https://github.com/XamFormsExtended/Xfx.Controls) to do the cardview.

Comment: What is your project link options?

Comment: https://github.com/XamFormsExtended/Xfx.Controls

Comment: I mean what is your Android project Linking option? You could found it in your android `Properties -> Android options -> Linking`

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT its none.

Comment: that's wired, I test your code on my side and it works fine, would you mind sharing a basic demo so that we could reproduce this issue on our side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPADTE: For me this is caused but the Xamarin Forms Nuget package 3.3.0.967582 -> 3.4.0.10008975. Reverting this package removes the exception.

This is not an answer but a comment (with pictures) since I can't add images to a comment.

I am having this issue as well. It started today when I updated all the Nugets. Not sure which update is causing it yet, but here are the packages that were updated.

I'll report back with any new findings.

[image]